# has and belongs to many form doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my app there is a has_many :through relationship between `survey` and `question`:

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :questions, through: :answers
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :surveys, through: :answers
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :survey
  belongs_to :question
end
```

I have a form to add a new survey which contains `question` checkboxes:

```
= form_for @survey, html: { class: "form-horizontal"} do |f|
  = render "layouts/messages", target: @survey
  .form-group
    = f.label I18n.t('.survey.form.name')
    = f.text_field :name, class: "form-control"
  .form-group
    = f.label I18n.t('.survey.form.questions')
    %ul
      = hidden_field_tag "survey[question_ids][]", nil
      - @questions.each do |question|
        %li.checkbox
          = check_box_tag "survey[question_ids][]", question.id, @survey.question_ids.include?(question.id)
          = question.intro
  .form-group
    .controls
      = f.submit(class: 'btn btn-default', value: I18n.t('.general.form.save'))
```

And the `survey` controller `create` action looks like this:

```
 def create
    @survey = Survey.new(survey_params)
    if @survey.save
      redirect_to surveys_path, notice: I18n.t('.survey.messages.created')
    else
      render action: "new"
    end
 end

 private
 def survey_params
   params.require(:survey).permit(:name, :question_ids => [])
 end
```

When I fill in the form and submit it, it will not get save, I only see a rollback in the server log:

```
Started POST "/surveys" for ::1 at 2015-05-24 12:29:00 +0200
Processing by SurveysController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "survey"=>{"name"=>"fdfdfd", "question_ids"=>["", "1", "2"]}, "commit"=>"Opslaan"}
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
```

So what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this is validation error. Try temporary replace `save` to `save!`. It should cause exception and it give you ability to investigate problem more details.

Comment: It was, there where 2 other mandatory attributes in `answer`, which were empty now, because only `question_id` and `survey_id` are filled.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@survey = Survey.build(survey_params)
```

in `SurveysController`.